# Failed to play mp4 video directly from URL in Android platform, is there any solution?

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video from URL on videoView. Video extension is mp4, and the problem is that an error appears like this :

[image]

and the logcat was like this:

![enter image description here][2]

Actually I found many questions here on stackoverflow.com but nothing were convenient. The problem is with mp4 format, I tried 3gp and it worked fine. I don't want to download the video then play it and I don't want to convert it to 3gp.

Appreciate your help.

**EDIT**:: Here is the code snippet

```
     String LINK =  "https://********/cbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcb.mp4";
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);  
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

**Edit**:

I don't know how to apply this recommendation from android site:

```
  For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom.
  For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM containers, audio and video samples corresponding to the same time offset may be no more than 500 KB apart. To minimize this audio/video drift, consider interleaving audio and video in smaller chunk sizes.
```

Comment: Put some code in order to see what can be causing that

Comment: It worked for another mp4 video with http ... my video aboove is HTTPS and needs SSL certificate so there is another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Giuseppe said `HTTPS` could be the problem, if you are using an Android version before 3.1.
If see it over here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html 
it says:

> Note: HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1.

**Edit:**
Ensure that you in your manifest file you have the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also test the video playing on a real device because sometimes the emulator has some problems.

Comment: See my edited answer. I have also tested that code on a real Device (Android 2.3.6) and it works.

Comment: How did you resolve the https in a gingerbread, it would be nice to know, thanks @Amt87